# (Java) Using lambda as comparator in Arrays.sort

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to write a function that takes two parameters, `int[] arr1` and `int[] arr2`. Then, it should sort `arr1` in the order given in `arr2`. For example, if `arr1` is `[5,7,9,10,7,5]` and `arr2` is `[7,9,10,5]`, the function should return `[7,7,9,10,5,5]`, sorting `arr1` in the order elements in `arr2` are indexed.

I wrote my code as below, but I keep on getting an error at Arrays.sort. I think I am using lambda incorrectly. Can you specify what I am doing wrong?

```
public int[] relativeSortArray(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {

    Map<Integer, Integer> elemToInd = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        elemToInd.put(arr2[i], i);
    }

    Arrays.sort(arr1, (int n1, int n2) -> elemToInd.get(n1) - elemToInd.get(n2));

    return arr1;
}
```

Comment: Just a question: why would you want to "copy" a sort order that you already have (i.e., why not just use `arr2`)?

Comment: primitive types can't be used with generics

Comment: @ernest_k I thought it would increase time complexity to go through arr2 to find index of each element every time I do compare, doesn't it?

Comment: does arr2[] always holds indices of elements? I.e., always has numbers between 0..N-1 (N is the size of arr1[]) and no duplicates? If that's the case, it's easy to create a new array and copy according to the indices of arr2[]

Comment: @nimrodm arr2 has no duplicates but arr1 can have duplicates. e.g arr1 [0,0,0,100,100], arr2 [100,0] => output [100,100,0,0,0]

Comment: @wWw: I was hoping arr2[] would have indices into arr1[] like your original example. The [100,0] example kills this assumption. So I guess you have to use the hash and convert the int[] to Integer[] or List<Integer>

Answer (score 3):

You can change the type of `arr1` (and of course return type), so that types conform (to `Integer[]`) and write simply:

```
Arrays.sort(arr1, Comparator.comparing(elemToInd::get));
```

But what you're doing is quite confusing. You cannot use generics with primitives, just reach to `Arrays` clas for helper methods. On the other hand for collections you can invoke `sort` method on them.

Answer (score 0):

```
 package java.util;   
 public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

you can see when you use this method, Comparator type must super T ,so type of arr must be using Integer